# How to fix - Cannot find object/table in database error when it actually exists?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I made a console C# app in which I generate SQL to insert a row into a table info_table and then execute it. When I use the same C# code (with necessary modifications of course) in SSIS, I get an error saying that the table cannot be found.

```
Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has 
been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'info_table'.
```

I know there is a info_table in my database and it works in the console app. So, I tried to use the fully qualified name in my SSIS C# script instead of just info_table and the error went away. Why does this happen and how do I fix it ? I doubt if there is a problem with my SSIS connection string.

**My SSIS connection String (connection manager is ADO.NET type) -**

```
Data Source=.;User ID=admin;Initial Catalog=MaximDB;Persist 
Security Info=True;Application Name=SSIS-DataReader-{555000d
ddd-aaa-bbb-cccceee}LocalHost.MaximDB.admin;
```

**My console app connection String -**

```
"server=(local);database=MaximDB;integrated security=SSPI;";
```

**The C# objects to connect to the database -**

**For Console C# app -**

```
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(consoleString);
```

**For SSIS C# script -**

```
        String ssisDbConnMgr = "SAMPLE_DB";//Name of the connection 
        manager in SSIS, an ADO.NET type

        ConnectionManager connMgr;
        SqlConnection databaseConn;
        SqlCommand sqlCmd;
        connMgr = Dts.Connections[ssisDbConnMgr];
        databaseConn = (SqlConnection)connMgr.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
        sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
```

Comment: What is wrong with using the fully qualified path?  Is the default database schema dbo?  Did you change the database to a different schema?

Comment: @TTeeple - I could use the full name, but its cumbersome, given that I am generating the SQL. Also, I am interested in learning why I am facing this problem.

Comment: What about the other questions?

Comment: By "fully qualified path" do you mean `dbo.info_table` instead of `info_table`? If so, please always use the schema prefix; for further motivation, [read this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx).

Comment: can you provide the insert query that you are using

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Thanks for that tip. It makes sense to me. Can you also help me to find out why I am able to use only table name in console app, but not in ssis c# sript. Connection string seems to be the same, SQL is same, Machine is same, Visual Studio is same, C# objects to connect are same...then I wonder why this difference.

Comment: Your console app is using integrated security. Your SSIS is using an 
explicit user. They are likely evaluating into different default schemas

Comment: @Zeeshan - query = INSERT INTO ##Details(id, name)
SELECT id, name
FROM [dbo].[source_table]. I also tried just source_table.

Comment: try this query = "using MaximDB;INSERT INTO ##Details(id, name) SELECT id, name FROM [dbo].[source_table]"

Comment: @Zeeshan I think you meant `USE MaximDB;`, not `using`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I tried 'USE MaximDB' before my SQL statements and the SSIS package worked. I wonder why.

Comment: o yes... sorry for that

Comment: it worked because the database context got set to the right database.

Comment: @Zeeshan - I am not so sure about that. My SSIS connection string actually has MaximDB in context, but it still does not get set.

Comment: You need to verify that all tables are fully qualified in your SSIS package. If you have 1 table that is not fully qualified it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the table is not using the default schema (i.e., something besides "dbo").

Comment: how do I check if that is the case ?